# Shares count of Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, share

Regarding Graph API, shares count of post, shares count of post's insights and shares count displayed on page are not identical. I've assumed that these represent same count. Is my assumption wrong?

From post:
  https://graph.facebook.com/XXXX_YYYY

```
{
  "id" : "XXXX_YYYY",
  ...
  "shares": {
    "count": 1 !!!!!
  }
  ...
}
```

From post's insights:
  https://graph.facebook.com/XXXX_YYYY/insights

```
[
 ...
  {
    "id": "XXXX_YYYY/insights/post_storytellers_by_action_type/lifetime",
    "name": "post_storytellers_by_action_type",
    "period": "lifetime",
    "values": [
      {
        "value": {
          "like": 90,
          "share": 14, !!!!!
          "comment": 10
        }
      }
    ],
    "title": "Lifetime Talking About This (Post) by action type",
    "description": "Lifetime The number of unique people who created a story about your Page post, by action type. (Unique Users)"
  }
  ...
]
```

On facebook page: 4 shares !!!!!

Thanks.

Comment: I'm seeing similar issues.

I also have noticed that the post_storytellers insight and the sum of the post_storytellers_by_action_type don't add up.

Comment: Facebook's database operates on eventual consistency. For a popular post, it is entirely possible for the shares count to be "1" when you first encounter it and then be "14" when you access the second URL. There are a lot of users in the world, having 13 more people share the post between the two URL retrievals is completely feasible. It's a feature, not a bug!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the same problem on my side, api has had many issues since 2012 started (at least for me) , I think you have better luck reporting this as a bug on Facebook, they can give you a better insight and solve the problem on their side

Url : [Facebook Bugs](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs)